# Matlab function gradient for fminunc

Tags: algorithm, math, matlab, gradient

```
f = @(w) sum(log(1 + exp(-t .* (phis * w'))))/size(phis, 1) + coef * w*w';
options = optimset('Display', 'notify', 'MaxFunEvals', 2e+6, 'MaxIter', 2e+6);
w = fminunc(f, ones(1, size(phis, 2)), options);
```

- **phis** size is NxN+1
- **t** size is Nx1
- **coef** is const

I'm trying to minimize function *f*, firstly I was using **fminsearch** but it works long time, that's why now I use **fminunc**, but there is one problem: I need function gradient for acceleration. Can you help me please construct gradient for function *f*, coz I always get this warning:

```
Warning: Gradient must be provided for trust-region algorithm;
  using line-search algorithm instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called **logistic regression, with a L2-regularization**. There are far better ways to solve this problem than a call to a Matlab function, since the log-likelihood function is concave.

You should ask your question in [the statistical website](http://stats.stackexchange.com), or have a look at [my former question there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3511/).